# Collections sort Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

Hi guys i have 3 Collections, 
the first one I want sort per name, the second for email then last one I want sort for age. 
My question is it work using collections?

if I do it in sql like

```
sort by name,email,age
```

I know that it work right?

Im trying do it in java like this.

```
Collections.sort(listPeople, new Comparator<People>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final People o1, final People o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});

//then

Collections.sort(listPeople, new Comparator<People>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final People o1, final People o2) {
        return o1.getEmail().compareTo(o2.getEmail());
    }
});

//and then 

Collections.sort(listPeople, new Comparator<People>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final People o1, final People o2) {
        return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
    }
});
```

it work? or each collection Overwrite previous?

Comment: why dont you try running it and you tell us if it works

Comment: Classes should be named after a single instance. If an instance of your class represents a single person, name it `Person`, not `People`.

Comment: Your question is a bit contradictory. SQL `sort by name,email,age` (really, `order by`) sorts one set of row on multiple fields. But then you talk about 3 collections, each sorted on one field.Then your code sorts one collection 3 times. Please clarify.

Comment: Its just a example :P

Comment: What @Arkadiy wants is that you get more precise on your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to sort 3 different collections by different comparators or do you want to sort one collection with a comparator that sorts by name, but if names are equal then by email and if emails are equal then by age. In the current state it is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you successively sort the same collection than the operations will **override** the effects of the other sorting operations.

---

What you want can be accomplished by adjusting your custom comparator. First compare for the **name**, if elements are equal then compare by **email**, if again equal compare by **age**.

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
Collections.sort(listPeople, new Comparator<People>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final People o1, final People o2) {
        int nameOrder = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        if (nameOrder != 0) {
            return nameOrder;
        }

        // Elements names are equal, compare by their email
        int emailOrder = o1.getEmail().compareTo(o2.getEmail());
        if (emailOrder != 0) {
            return emailOrder ;
        }

        // Elements emails are equal, compare by their age
        int ageOrder = o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
        // Return that in any case as we do not have another sorting criteria
        return ageOrder;
    }
});
```

---

Since **Java 8** you can achieve the same with less code (see the answer of *@Eugene*):

```
Comparator.comparing(People::getName)
    .thenComparing(People::getEmail)
    .thenComparing(People::getAge));
```

This will create the same comparator than explained above.

Answer (score 6):

If I got it correct, you should be using the java-8 features here...

```
Collections.sort(listPeople, Comparator.comparing(People::getName)
                     .thenComparing(People::getEmail)
                     .thenComparing(People::getAge));
```

Comment: While this code surely solves the problem of OP it does not explain how it works. For me it sounds like OP struggles with some basics, possibly explanation helps more to get a basic understanding of how things work as just posting some magic code that does the trick.

Comment: @Zabuza ... and that is what your answer does indeed. Especially since this is tagged with `java-8` and I do *assume* the user is able to read this "magic code". Hey, I gave a plus one to your answer btw, so thx for filling he gap ;)

Comment: Oh, did not see the `java-8` tag, then I surely withdraw my objection :)

Comment: Or `listPeople.sort(...)`

Comment: @holi-java thx for tagging me for that question - I actually like it a lot. But I dont have an answer... I guess you will have to wait for someone else. sorry